# Как исправить ошибку 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Столкнулся с ошибкой не могу исправить

> BRAVOBET[51939:6184497] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard
>   named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle
>   
>   (loaded)'

Подскажите как убрать, я проверил везде стоит `Main`. Симуляторы загружены. Версии все есть. Я уже удалял `pod` и заново все загружал. Не могу разобраться что не так.

Comment: NSBundle у Вас какой используется? Добавьте код, в котором Вы обращаетесь к storyboard.

Comment: Да, я уже потом разобрался.Надо было галочку в проекте поставить для этого bundle.

Comment: В таком случае добавьте Ваш ответ на данный вопрос, возможно кому-нибудь он когда-нибудь пригодится.